# multi select list only have vertical scrollbar

Tags: css

I've got a multi select list, but it only gives me an vertical scrollbar. I even want a horizontal scrollbar if the content is wider than the select list.

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:storedProceduresInDB1, selectedOptions:selectedStoredProceduresInDb1"> </select>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/1457/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Knockout's problem. You could add `overflow: auto;` to `.list` CSS class and remove `width: 100%;` from `.list select[multiple]`.
It is will add horizontal scroll to div, not to select. You can rewrite you HTML to make it more friendly looking.